# Change Django Boolean value from default value "False" to something like "No"

Tags: python, django, boolean

I have a Boolean value which is false, but I want it to say something like "No" rather than "False" when printed on the web page.

The same goes for printing "Yes" instead of "True" if it were true. I'm assuming this is possible!

Code in models:

```
urgent = models.BooleanField()
```

Code in template:

```
<p>Upvotes: {{ ticket.urgent}}</p>
```

Now, to print this sounds weird:

```
Urgent: False
```

But this sounds more natural, better UX etc.:

```
Urgent: No
```

Comment: This is simple, but is entirely a matter for the template where you are displaying that data. You need to show us that template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use [`yesno`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno)

> Maps values for True, False, and (optionally) None, to the strings “yes”, “no”, “maybe”, or a custom mapping passed as a comma-separated list, and returns one of those strings according to the value:

```
<p>Upvotes: {{ ticket.upvotes|yesno }}</p>
```

Comment: Tiny note, but in the provided example code this will print "yes" and "no" in lower case. Either you need to add additional arguments (as the explanation describes) or you need to add use a filter to capitalise the output, for instance [capfirst](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#capfirst)

Comment: Thanks @Sayse! What I did was ```<p>Urgent: {{ ticket.urgent|yesno:"Yes,No" }}</p>```

Answer (score 0):

You can write [custom model field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-values-to-python-objects)

something like (i dont checked)

```
class CustomBoolean(models.Field):
# ...

def to_python(self, value):
        if value == 'No':
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: I think checking the answer before providing it is kind of a minimum requirement.